# Почему данные повторно записываются в таблицу? Почему они не сбрасываются после применения к ним функции unset()?

Tags: php, mysql, post, webforms, unset

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <style type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
            table {
                border-collapse: collapse;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"] ?>" method="POST">
            <label for="species">Вид</label>
            <input type="text" name="species" id="species"><br>
            <label for="name">Имя</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name"><br>
            <label for="age">Возраст</label>            
            <input type="text" name="age" id="age"><br>
            <input type="hidden" name="check" value="yes">
            <input type="submit" value="Внести данные">          
        </form>
        <?php
         echo $_POST["species"] . " " . $_POST["name"] . " " . $_POST["age"] . "<br>";
         require_once "../reg file/login.php";
         $connection = new mysqli($hn, $un, $pw, $db);
         function get_post($connection, $var) {
             return $connection->real_escape_string($_POST[$var]);
         }
//Код проверки на существование таблицы
         $query = "SELECT * FROM cats LIMIT 1";
         if (!$connection->query($query)) {

              $query = "CREATE TABLE cats(species VARCHAR(128) NOT NULL,"
                 . "name VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,"
                 . "age INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,"
                 . "id SMALLINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                 . "PRIMARY KEY(id))";
              $result = $connection->query($query);
              if (!$result) {
                die("Не удалось создать таблицу.");
              }
              mysqli_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); 
              mysqli_query("SET CHARACTER SET 'utf8'");
              mysqli_query("SET SESSION collation_connection = 'utf8_general_ci'");
          }
//Проверка отправки формы 
         if (isset($_POST["check"])) {

            $species = get_post($connection, "species");
            $name = get_post($connection, "name");
            $age = get_post($connection, "age");
         }
//Проверка корректности введенных данных
         if (!empty($species) && !empty($name) && !empty($age)) {

             echo $species . " " . $name . " " . $age . "<br>";
             $query = "INSERT INTO cats(species, name, age)"
                     . "VALUES('$species', '$name', $age)";
             $result = $connection->query($query);
             if (!$result) {
                die("Не удалось выполнить запрос к БД.");
             }
         }
         else if (isset($_POST["check"]) && (isset($species) xor isset($name) xor isset($age))) {

             echo "Вы не ввели одно или несколько полей.<br>";
         }  

//////Вывод таблицы
         echo "<table>";
         echo "<tr><th>Вид</th><th>Имя</th><th>Возраст</th><th>ID</th></tr>";

         $query = "SELECT * FROM cats";
         $result = $connection->query($query);
         $rows = $result->num_rows;
         for ($i = 1; $i <= $rows; $i++) {

           $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
           echo "<tr>";

             <?php
             echo "<td>" . $row["species"] . "</td>" . " ";
             echo "<td>" . $row["name"] . "</td>" .  " ";
             echo "<td>" . $row["age"] . "</td>" . " ";
             echo "<td>" . $row["id"] . "</td>";
             echo "</tr>";
         }
         echo "</table>";
        ///Сброс данных
         unset($_POST["species"], $_POST["name"], $_POST["age"]);
         echo $_POST["species"] . " " . $_POST["name"] . " " . $_POST["age"] . "<br>";
         $result->close();
         $connection->close();
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Я пишу unset() в конце скрипта, чтобы избежать повторной записи данных в таблицу при перезапуске страницы. Если отправить данные из формы, а потом перезапустить страницу, то эти данные запишутся в таблицу еще раз.
После сброса данных я вывожу их и, как и ожидалось, генерируются ошибки. Но если перезапустить страницу, то инструкции echo в начале скрипта сработают без ошибок и данные повторно запишутся в таблицу. Почему так? Ведь я же сбросил данные элементы массива `$_POST` и в конце скрипта даже генерировались ошибки о том, что  таких индексов не существует.
**Почему мой способ не работает и как сделать так, чтобы предотвратить повторную запись данных в таблицу?**

Comment: Вас браузер разве не предупреждает что данные будут отправлены заново/повторно?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно следить за формой, а не за POSTом, потому что если после POST запроса к примеру нажать f5(обновить страницу), то от вас улетит еще один POST запрос с теми же данными. Можно к примеру чистить форму поле успешной операции, либо использовать редирект на нужную страницу. А то что вы пишите unset() в конце скрипта особо не поможет. Почему - потому что PHP скрипт запускается, отрабатывает и "умирает". Если речь шла бы о сессии, то unset() еще был бы полезен.

Comment: А как чистить форму? Что Вы имеете в виду?